# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:19,lvl:2000},{id:16,lvl:2000}]},display:{Name:"The Destroyer 2000",Lore:["The Sword That Beats All!"]}}
```

This is my command and it doesn't work. I'm just trying to put double enchants on it. I've copy and pasted everything and nothing works!

Does anyone have a answer, a hint or a clue?

Answer (score 4):

There is a `}` too much at the end of the `ench`-tag, closing the entire data tag early. Then the game is left with gibberish that makes no sense, thus failing the command.

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:19,lvl:2000},{id:16,lvl:2000}],display:{Name:"The Destroyer 2000",Lore:["The Sword That Beats All!"]}}
```